# MAUI XAML WYSIWYG editor

Tags: .net, xaml, maui

I've Googled for a tool, but it seems to be only paid tools in 3dr party packages. Does Microsoft provide any WYSIWYG (like Blend) for MAUI?
My goal is to find a WYSIWYG tool for MAUI dialogs/pages.

Comment: No there is not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no tool for that right now and also no plans on the roadmap to create something for that officially.

Some work is going on for [FigmaSharp](https://github.com/microsoft/FigmaSharp) and maybe other tools I'm not aware of.